# Return Bit Value based on previous records by Category

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

How would I return TRUE or FALSE if four of the last six records failed for a given MAKEID?  So there has to be 4 failures (or FALSE records) in the last six

```
MAKEID       FAILURES    CREATEDATE
101          TRUE        12/1/2015
101          FALSE       12/5/2015
101          TRUE        12/6/2015
101          FALSE       12/8/2015
101          TRUE        12/10/2015
101          FALSE       12/15/2015
101          FALSE       1/1/2016
101          FALSE       1/2/2016
102          TRUE        12/2/2015
102          TRUE        12/4/2015
102          FALSE       12/5/2015
102          TRUE        12/6/2015
102          FALSE       12/7/2015
102          TRUE        1/1/2016
```

Query would return the following:

```
MAKEID    FOUROFLASTSIXFAILED
101       TRUE
102       FALSE
```

Requirement is there needs to be 4 or more failures in last six records.  So if there were 4, 5, or 6 failures in the last six records FOUROFLASTSIXFAILED would return TRUE.  If there were only 1, 2, 3 records for a given MAKEID that would return FALSE because there at least needs to be 4 failures in previous six records.

Comment: What if a MAKEID only has 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rows? What if a MAKEID has 5 or 6 failures in the last 6, should that also return true? Just trying to remove ambiguity and capture edge cases you either haven't hit or haven't thought to share.

Comment: Only for the last 6 rows or any row where there were 4 failures?

Comment: @dnoeth I thought that part was clear - only the latest six rows.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  There has to be 4 failures in last 6 records. If there are only 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rows that doesnt meet the condition, so would return FALSE.  If last 6 had 5 or 6 failures that too doesnt meet condition, so would return FALSE.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please update the question to make it more accurate to your actual requirements? Thanks. Also, is your desired output accurate? The table seems to indicate failure = true 4 times for 102, but not for 101, so shouldn't it be false then true rather than true / false? (This is what happens when you try to change / simplify / obfuscate your real problem. It causes more problems.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach (but please, stop changing your requirements):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(MAKEID INT, FAILURES varchar(5), CREATEDATE date);

INSERT @x VALUES
(101,'TRUE ','20151201'),    (101,'FALSE','20151205'),    (101,'TRUE ','20151206'),
(101,'FALSE','20151208'),    (101,'TRUE ','20151210'),    (101,'FALSE','20151215'),
(101,'FALSE','20160101'),    (101,'FALSE','20160102'),    (102,'TRUE ','20151202'),
(102,'TRUE ','20151204'),    (102,'FALSE','20151205'),    (102,'TRUE ','20151206'),
(102,'FALSE','20151207'),    (102,'TRUE ','20160101');

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT MAKEID, FAILURES,
    -- allow us to identify the last 6 rows:
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MAKEID ORDER BY CREATEDATE DESC)
  FROM @x
)
SELECT MAKEID, FOUROFLASTSIXFAILED = CASE 
  -- make sure there have been at least 6 tests - though this may change:
    WHEN COUNT(*) >= 6 
  -- make sure *at least* 4 of those have failed *within the last 6*
  -- though this may change (again), too:
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN rn <= 6 AND FAILURES = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) >= 4 
  THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END 
FROM x 
GROUP BY MAKEID
ORDER BY MAKEID;
```

Results (I think these are right, as opposed to the desired output stated in your question, which seem to conflict with your stated requirements):

```
MAKEID    FOUROFLASTSIXFAILED
------    -------------------
101       FALSE
102       TRUE
```

It would seem to me that `MAKEID = 102` is the only one that has failed exactly four times out of its last six entries, unless the `FAILURES` column in the original table really represents `NOT_FAILURES`.

Comment: Sorry about this, but how would the query be modified if requirement was there needed to be 4 or more failures in last six records?  So if there were 4, 5, or 6 failures in the last six records FOUROFLASTSIXFAILED would return TRUE.  If there were only 1, 2, 3 records for a given MAKEID that would return FALSE because there at least needs to be 4 failures in previous six records.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @obautista So your requirement changed back again to "four or more" from "exactly four"? How do you stay on top of code when your requirements change so often? Anyway you would change `END) = 4` to `END) >= 4`. Also your new requirements aren't clear about what you want to do in the case where there are 4 rows or 5 rows, and 4 of those are failures.